# Why do only some footnotes appear in superscript when set in an OTF font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, footnotes, superscripts

In the example below, the numbers 1-3 are in superscript as footnote markers while 4-9 and 0 are not. This occurs when the main font is Quattrocento Sans (using `\setmainfont{Quattrocento Sans}`) but not if there is no `\setmainfont` declaration.

There is no extra configuration of the footnotes which are produced from urls with `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{. #2 \url{#1}}}`

What is going on? is it font problem (since i get the same results on OSX and Debian)? xetex? something else?

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235291/7883

Comment: let me guess: you're loading `xltxtra` somehow? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80028/5049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem is caused by a combination of `xltxtra` redefining `\textsuperscript` and the font not containing true superiors for all numbers. The `xltxtra` package is loaded from one of the pandoc templates and superscripts appear as expected when it's removed. There are more details in answers to some similar questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235291/7883) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80028/5049).